# I don't know how to deal with the error in input.getaxis("Vertical")?

Tags: c#-3.0, unity-game-engine

I have tried checking the documentation and it seems correct to me but still I'm getting an error when i try to build this project.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        Input side = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Input up = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (side, 0.0f, up);
        rb.AddForce (movement);
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your mistakes are on these two lines:

```
Input side = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
Input up = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

`Input.GetAxis` returns `float` but you are assigning that to `Input` which is **not** a `float` and does **not** even exist. So, replace `Input side` and `Input up` with `float side` and `float up`.

```
    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization

    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame



    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        float side = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float up = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(side, 0.0f, up);

        rb.AddForce(movement);


    }
}
```